# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager pageLoaded event caching function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I've got a master page that contains this code at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(closeLoading);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(parseData);
</script>
</form>
```

the parseData() function I'm creating inside the main page and I'm adding functions to it based on each page load.  parseData IS called after every AJAX refresh, but it appears to only call the contents of the function from BEFORE the request.  If I hit F5 to refresh the page again, it will properly call all of the newly added content in the parseData function.

Does this function cache that data?  How can I make sure it calls the newly created contents of the parseData function?

Comment: I have got it solved... see this link.. resolved or fixed by [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13685729/1872932) coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the research I did, this is a problem with MS AJAX UpdatePanels and you are really better off not using them.  I revised my JavaScript to pull data from hidden form fields instead so the JavaScript functions never changed and was able to get this working.